# FlatBuffer: how to construct a table with an optional sub-struct/sub-table

Tags: flatbuffers

I have a root table and inside the table an optional struct/table.  The inner table is optional--it may or may not construct based on other conditions.

Here is an example [FlatBuffer schema](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/md__schemas.html):

```
struct A {
    value:bool;
}

table B {
    ...
}

table C {
    ...
    a:A;
    b:B;
    ...
}
```

Whether to construct A/B is based on other conditions.

Since you aren't allowed to use [FlatBufferBuilder](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/classflatbuffers_1_1_flat_buffer_builder.html) nested, do I have to construct them first even they are not needed, and then `add_a`/`add_b` very late, after create `Cbuilder` based on other conditions?

In C++, I didn't figure out a proper way to do that. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Be sure to use proper names and link to what you're taking about...since if you say something like "I have a flatbuffer" all lowercase, no one knows if it's a thing you're just making up or not!  (I've tried to clarify/link what you are talking about, as people (e.g. me) don't necessarily have any idea what a "FlatBuffer" is...so what you posted just looked like invalid C++ syntax.)

Comment: I think i already used the upper case as "Flatbuffer" in the title and tagged with "flatbuffers". I guess I shouldn't tag "C++" to bother people, even i am asking the help of the solution implemented in C++?

Comment: It's not a problem--just looked like invalid C++ syntax or pseudocode at first glance.  But there are a lot of questions asked here.  If you can add bits from your actual code it could be helpful.  Phrases like "doesn't allow to use builder nested" can mean many things--what exactly is a builder (I tried to link a guess, to give you an example of markdown linking, and how it could help).  It's not only helpful to understanding your question to get an answer, but a more complete question can be informative for others who might come searching on FlatBuffers later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you construct objects in pre-order (not nested) doesn't make optional construction any different:

```
flatbuffers::Offset<B> bo;  // default 0, so unused.
if (my_conditions) {
  bo = CreateB(fbb, ..);
}
Cbuilder cb;
if (my_conditions) {
  cb.add_a(A(..));  // Structs must be created inline.
}
cb.add_b(bo);  // This will not be stored if 0.
...
```

Comment: Thanks! Did similar, with  `int b = 0;` and then pass `offset.o` to `b`.